# Azure BotFramework

Tags: botframework

I was I asked to create this post.  I am using the bot service on azure.  I created a bot and everything worked great.  Then I deleted the bot and created a new on and now I get Microsoft App ID is not a valid GUID.  This happens when I hit the create bot button.  Thank you for all your help.

Comment: Are u using a new guid?

Comment: Please give a lot more information:
Are you using the AppId and App Passcode from the new bot registration?
Did you put that new infomration in your source code?
Can you screenshot the exact error message on this post (if you can't post pictures, link to it).

Comment: here are 5 screen shots all I do is log in to azure create new bot service and go through the prompts.  I choose unique names that I have never used before and I get this error.

Comment: Sorry will not allow me to upload screen shots I will work on getting up links to them, but the jist of it is all I do is go through the prompts and I use unique names that have never been used and I get this error

Comment: https://1drv.ms/i/s!AtpqDDxPNBQ6gYhFM3uILhBQimki7g

Comment: https://1drv.ms/i/s!AtpqDDxPNBQ6gYhCrMWhcwYf2Z_hww

Comment: https://1drv.ms/i/s!AtpqDDxPNBQ6gYhCrMWhcwYf2Z_hww

Comment: then it creates a unique id.  with a name I have never used.  https://1drv.ms/i/s!AtpqDDxPNBQ6gYhGcNnCgEFfGhGaKg

Comment: https://1drv.ms/i/s!AtpqDDxPNBQ6gYhDCH-DxhtJ5kL1lQ

Answer (score 1):

I've had similar errors when trying to re-create the bot with the same name right after I had deleted it.  If possible, try to use a different name for the bot.

Also, I noticed that when I deleted the Bot Service from Azure, it didn’t delete the bot that is registered on the bot framework portal (dev.botframework.com).  You should manually delete the bot there also.

Answer (score 0):

The App Id is a Guid that corresponds to your bot's App Id in dev.botframework.net  The App Name is different.  It looks like you've got your App Name (Bot handle, or Bot Id) in place of your App Id on the Bot Service Create blade.

This is your App Id:

[image]

Comment: It just generates the app id every time I create a new name.  I have NO control of the App ID it gives me.  Do ya have any suggestions of what I should do different.  Thank you for taking the time to comment.

Comment: Use the AppId it gives you.  This isn't something that has to be exposed to users of your Bot. It needs to be a corresponding Microsoft Application Id.  Your App Name is NOT your App Id.

Comment: When going through the setup a choose a complete unique name for my app and I do not associate it with any other name.  Then it generates a new app id.  but after all that I still get that error.  the thing that bums me out is it worked the first time I created it.